# $scope.$on calling multiple times in a controller

Tags: angularjs

I called an event using $rootscope.$broadcast and  $scope.$on firing muiltple times.
Here is my code.
controllerA:

```
$scope.setView =function(){
service.hideView();
}
```

In service:

```
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
                .title('clic ok or cancel')
                .targetEvent()
                .ok('OK')
                .cancel('Cancel');           
            confirm._options.template = '<md-dialog md-theme="{{ dialog.theme }}" aria-label="{{ dialog.ariaLabel }}" ng-class="dialog.css">' +
                     '   <md-dialog-content class="md-dialog-content" role="document" tabIndex="-1" style="order:0 !important">' + 
                      '      <h2 class="md-title">' + 
                       '         {{ dialog.title }}' + 
                        '    </h2>' + 
                         '   <div ng-if="::dialog.mdHtmlContent" class="md-dialog-content-body"ng-bind-html="::dialog.mdHtmlContent"></div>' + 
                          '  <div ng-if="::!dialog.mdHtmlContent" class="md-dialog-content-body">' + 
                           '     <p>{{::dialog.mdTextContent}}</p>' + 
                            '</div>' + 
                        '</md-dialog-content>' + 
                        '<md-dialog-actions>' + 
                       '     <md-button ng-if="dialog.$type == \'confirm\'"ng-click="dialog.abort()" class="md-primary">{{ dialog.cancel }}</md-button>' + 
                      '      <md-button ng-click="dialog.hide()" class="md-primary" md-autofocus="dialog.$type!=\'confirm\'">{{ dialog.ok }}</md-button>' + 
                     '   </md-dialog-actions>' + 
                    '</md-dialog>';

            $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("eventFired",{});                    
            }, function() {

            });
```

In controllerB:

```
$scope.$on("eventFired",function(){
$scope.hideTemplate();
});
```

in controler B it is calling hideTemplate 3 times. how to fix this  one?

Comment: I'm not sure what your ultimate use is here, but this looks like a pretty expensive solution for responding to a confirmation dialog.

Comment: before close the view I need to get user's input .so I used confirmation dialog and then using that response I am calling eventFired.

Comment: I'm trying to decorate `$mdDialog` and also see the show-function being called 3 times.